# Can not force \newline within \longtable

Tags: line-breaking, longtable

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{8cm}}

A \newline B & C \newline D & E \\ 

\end{tabular}
```

I tried creating a table as shown in the above MWE, the table is longer than 1 page and its not going to the second page, part of the table is cut off at the bottom.

I tried using `\begin{longtable}`  in place of `\begin{tabular}` and it gave me error. am I doing anything wrong, can I not use `\newline` to force line break within a cell in `\longtable` environment?

Comment: You can't break a cell across pages; page breaks are allowed only between table rows.

Comment: @egreg: I think OP wants to add a newline in a row and not force it to span multiple pages. However I find it hard to believe that that tabular spans more than half a page.

Comment: @AKU: Can you give a complete MWE, that is compilable (with preamble)?

Answer (score 2):

When you say you tried `\begin{longtable}`, did you also put `\usepackage{longtable}` in your preamble?  What was the error it gave?

With `\usepackage{longtable}` in the preamble it gives the expected output, something like

A     |C     |E
B     |D     |

and no errors.

Comment: This is not an answer; please use the comments when asking for more information.

Comment: I can now, but I only had 41 rep before so couldn't.  Also, `\usepackage{longtable}` might have been the fix the OP was looking for, so though worded as a question it was meant as a tentative answer.

Comment: chris - you are right, I thought I included \usepackage{longtable} but it was not there. sorry to miss the obvious and post question here in Panic. Thanks for your help

Comment: Aku, no problem - I thought it was worth suggesting the easy thing first.